# What does it mean if I have a high R2 but low RMSE and low MAE

Tags: machine-learning, regression, linear-regression

I just ran a linear regression on my data and got unusually low values for my MAE and RSME while also getting a higher value for my R2.  This makes me think there must be something wrong with my data distributions or I'm overfitting.   Any idea what could cause this?
Thanks

For reference-

```
r2:.9625108
rmse: 0.003753331
mae: 0.003636361
```

Comment: That is what you should expect.  MAE and RMSE are errors. Good values are low.  For R2 the best values are high (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination) )

Comment: yeah it looks a bit too good, then again rmse always depends on the scale of your response. Did you try splitting the data into test and train? If it is overfitting, you will see it perform poorly in the test

Comment: but before that, what are you using your linear regression for?